# Why do I not have the unsung hero badge?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges, zero-score-badges

I just got awarded the "Tireless" badge on StackOverflow, and have inspected my answers to check if I qualify for the "Unsung Hero" badge.

I have written a query [available here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/345/how-unsung-am-i?UserId=102441), that clearly says that 12/30 accepted answers have zero score. That's both more than 25% and 10.

Do I have to wait a day after getting the "Tireless" badge before getting the "Unsung Hero" one?

Comment: By "Tireless" did you mean "Tenacious"?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/121138/a-day-accounted-for-how-unsung-am-i

Comment: Here is a query updated https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228150/how-unsung-am-i-fixed-ver-includes

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Accepting your own answer on your own question is ignored from all calculations

Comment: Ooh. Hadn't thought of that. I'll have another look.

Comment: Yup. That did the trick. I've updated the query.

Answer (score 11):

I've forked @Eric's "How unsung am I" and added the 10 days requirement - just enter your Stack Overflow id and you'll get all the needed stats: [How close am I to unsung hero badge](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/121674/how-close-am-i-to-unsung-hero-badge-including-10-days-requirement)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185560/209357