# What's missing to get the unsung hero badge?

Tags: support, zero-score-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long do Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded)

I was just having a look at my questions today and I'm wondering why the Unsung hero badge hasn't been awarded.

I have 14 zero-score accepted answers (not included self-answered questions) for a total of 45 accepted answers. It's more than 10 zero score accepted answers and about 30% of total. So should the badge have been awarded or am I missing something?

Comment: Are all the answers older than 10 days? [That's a requirement not mentioned on the Badges page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258) to prevent users quick-posting to get it.

Comment: In general, whenever you're thinking you have earned a badge but haven't seen it awarded yet, the best thing to do is wait at least 24-48 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meet the criterion according to the query [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57528/why-do-i-not-have-the-unsung-hero-badge), then I think the answer is [time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded).

You need to wait at least 10 days.  Some of your newest zero score answers are only 2 or 3 days old (and haven't really had a chance to get votes yet).

Comment: thanks for your answer, you can remove the questions. I guess I indeed need to wait for a few days.

Comment: Yep.  Sorry.  I've spent those days too & inadvertently things get one friggin' up-vote.  bah.  Makes me wonder if these badges were [ill-conceived](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56897/was-the-unsung-hero-a-bad-idea-to-implement).